# Looking for a synonym, when something is dedicated to something, like a movie

Tags: synonyms

To elaborate, when a movie for example borrows heavily from something, when you could call it a love letter to that something. It's on the tip of my tongue, and been killing me for a while now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Homage*, *tribute*, *tip of the hat*, *nod of the head*, etc.

Comment: derivative? ...

Comment: *pastiche*, *send-up*, *takeoff*

Comment: Can you give an example of such a movie and explain how it was a love letter to a person, event, earlier movie ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the word *hommage*.  It's the French word for "homage", but in English, it [means something specific](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hommage):

> A homage, especially something in an artwork which has been done in respectful imitation of another artist.

It's pronounced in that Frenchified way (/oʊˈmɒːʒ/ instead of /ˈhɑmɪdʒ/) and usually italicized in print.

> **Fan:** Was the scene between you and Sandy Bates at the wax museum a *hommage* to Vincent Price's horror movie, *The House of Wax*?
>   **Tony:** An *hommage*? Not exactly. We just stole the idea outright.

Answer (score 5):

**"an ode to..."** comes to mind.  It originally referred to any lyric poem dedicated to someone or something. It can also refer to a film or a piece of music, though.   Beethoven's Symphony nº9, for instance, is also known as **"Ode to Joy"**.

> - [**ode**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ode) (noun) - "a poem in which a person expresses a strong feeling of love or respect for someone or something."